# Update localStorage Value on submit in Typescript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage

I want to update values within an Array of Objects saved to my localStorage.

The Objects are already in my localStorage. I want to update the progress.

The key is skills and the value is the Array.

I have a form with two sliders on my page which tracks the time(progress). On Submit I want to update the progress.

I think I have a major misunderstanding of how this works because I don't get it to work.

```
[
{category: "crafting"
description: "Prepare yourself for cold times"
imageSrc: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621490153925-439fbe544722?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80"
isDone: false
progress: 500
title: "Knitting"},
{category: "mental"
description: "Take control over your mind"
imageSrc: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554244933-d876deb6b2ff?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80"
isDone: false
progress: 500
title: "Meditation"}]
```

This is my handleSubmit function which updates the Value. Its controlled by a form with 2 Sliders (mins) (hrs)

```
  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const hrs = parseInt(hours);
    const mins = parseInt(minutes);
    const addedHours = value + hrs + mins * 0.015;
    setValue(addedHours);
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of my localStorage:
[localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqHfp.png)

Here is the whole code of the page:

```
export default function DetailPage(): JSX.Element {
  const [hours, setHours] = useState('0');
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState('0');
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const history = useHistory();
  const { skills } = useLocalStorageSkills();



  const { title }: { title: string } = useParams();
  const filteredSkills = skills.filter(
    (skills) => skills.title === String(title)
  );

  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const hrs = parseInt(hours);
    const mins = parseInt(minutes);
    const addedHours = value + hrs + mins * 0.015;
    setValue(addedHours);
  }

  const ranking =
    value === 0
      ? '0'
      : value < 99
      ? '1'
      : value > 100 && value < 199
      ? '2'
      : value > 200 && value < 299
      ? '3'
      : value > 300 && value < 399
      ? '4'
      : '5';

  const ranktrack = JSON.stringify(ranking);
  localStorage.setItem('ranking', ranking);

  const ranktrackparsed = JSON.parse(ranktrack);
  localStorage.getItem('ranking');

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {filteredSkills.map((skills) => (
        <Header
          {...skills}
          key={skills.title}
          title={skills.title}
          type="detail"
          imageSrc={skills.imageSrc}
          onClick={() => {
            history.push('/');
          }}
        />
      ))}

      <main className={styles.main}>
        {filteredSkills.map((skills) => (
          <ProgressTrack
            value={(skills.progress - value).toFixed(1)}
            rank={ranktrackparsed}
          />
        ))}
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Rangeslider
            size="hours"
            value={hours}
            min={'0'}
            max={'24'}
            onChange={(event) => setHours(event.target.value)}
          />
          <Rangeslider
            size="minutes"
            value={minutes}
            min={'0'}
            max={'59'}
            onChange={(event) => setMinutes(event.target.value)}
          />
          <ActionButton
            children={'Submit'}
            type={'submit'}
            style="primary"
          ></ActionButton>
        </form>
        {filteredSkills.map((skills) => (
          <ProgressBar
            percentageVal={value}
            textVal={value.toFixed(1)}
            minValue={1}
            maxValue={500}
            children={skills.description}
          />
        ))}
      </main>
      <Navigation activeLink={'add'} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I have a custom hook, to use localStorage:

```
import useLocalStorage from './useLocalStorage';
import type { Skill } from '../../types';

export default function useLocalStorageSkills(): {
  skills: Skill[];
  addSkill: (skills: Skill) => void;
  removeSkill: (newSkill: Skill) => void;
  editSkill: (oldSkill: Skill, newSkill: Skill) => void;
} {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useLocalStorage<Skill[]>('skills', []);

  function addSkill(skill: Skill) {
    setSkills([...skills, skill]);
  }

  function removeSkill(newSkill: Skill) {
    setSkills(skills.filter((skill) => skill !== newSkill));
  }

  function editSkill(deleteSkill: Skill, newSkill: Skill) {
    setSkills([
      ...skills.filter((skill) => skill.title !== deleteSkill.title),
      newSkill,
    ]);
  }

  return { skills, addSkill, removeSkill, editSkill };
}
```

Its my first question, If you need more information, I will do my best to provide more.

Comment: So you want to save this object to localStorage am I right?

Comment: I think you should reformat your question so it is easier to understand

Comment: I edited my question for a better understanding.

Comment: Please add the code for `setValue`.

Comment: I added the whole code. setValue is the setter function of Reacts useState.

Comment: As far as I can see, there's nothing in your submit handler that updates the `skills` in localstorage.  It only updates state, which is not the same.

Comment: @Matt Morgan Yes, that is my problem. I don't know how to update the localStorage AND the state.
This is my first project, I cant really get my head around it.